# How to install enet using luarocks

Tags: lua, luarocks, enet

I tried to install enet for lua using luarocks. First, I checked out enet (the library) from github and compiled it:

```
svn co https://github.com/lsalzman/enet.git/trunk enet.git
cd enet.git
autoreconf -vfi
./configure && make && make install
```

This completed without errors. Then, I installed enet (the lua binding) via luarocks:

```
luarocks install enet
```

Again, no errors. However, if I try to `require "enet"`, it will always throw the error:

```
error loading module 'enet' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/enet.so':
        libenet.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

In case that it is important, I am doing this on a Raspberry Pi using Raspbian Wheezy. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by rebooting my Raspberry... This must've been the first time I actually had to restart it in order to install anything...

Comment: I suspect LuaRocks may not have called `ldconfig`, which is required to register newly installed shared libraries. Rebooting would also do the trick.

Comment: This would be a part of installing `enet` (the library) and not the LuaRocks module, so running `ldconfig` is not LuaRocks's responsibility; it expects library dependencies to be installed. OP should have done  `./configure && make && make install && ldconfig` (or enet upstream should have run `ldconfig` during `make install`).